# Change checkout table in order confirmation step

Tags: checkout, html, totals

How can I modify the totals table in the checkout? I need to change the output cells:

[image]

First display **Steuer = Tax**, then **Vesand = Shipping**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in this file

app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml

you also have to look in a layout of checkout. and find the totals.phtml file.

you will find the subtotal, grand total file in tax folder into app/desing/theme/default/default/tax/ here your subtotal file. this is in 1.9.1 Magento CE.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change this in Magento backend

Try goto

> System->Configuration->Sales->Checkout Total Sort Order.

Set the sorting order as you wish.